# Python - Class.function().function()

Tags: python, function, class

I have this problem from codewars.com: First n Primes numbers.
While I have no problem defining class Primes() and Primes.first(n1), I need to find the last prime numbers under the form: Primes.first(n1).last(n2). And I don't know how to define last(n2) without getting an error.

```
import math
class Primes():
    def first(self):
        primes = []
        count = 1
        prime = True
        while len(primes) != self:
            for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count)) + 1):
                if count % i == 0:
                    prime = False
                break
        if prime:
            primes.append(count)
        prime = True
        count += 1
        return primes

    def last(self):
        pass
```

If i try Primes.first(5).last(3) i get: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'last'.

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried and the error you are getting. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my questing with the code.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, there is no argument to `first` other than self. So, Primes().first(3) doesn't mean anything

Comment: Are you dead-set on having the exact syntax `Primes.first(5).last(3)`? If it's not mandatory, you're making a lot more work for yourself than if you did something like `getPrimesBetween(3,5)` (although there _aren't_ any primes between 3 and 5, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for)

Comment: The error is clear: `Primes.first(5)` returns a list, and you then try to access its attribute `last(3)`, which as the exception tells you, does not exist. What did you expect `Primes.first(5).last(3)` to actually do?

Comment: For example:

Primes.first(1)
# => [2]

Primes.first(2)
# => [2, 3]

Primes.first(5)
# => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]

Primes.first(20).last(5)
# => [53, 59, 61, 67, 71]

Answer (score 0):

... first returns a list.last() is trying to call a function named last on a list. A list does not have a function called last.

I think you want this.

```
class Primes(list):
    def first(self, amount):
        count = 1
        while len(self) < amount:
            prime = True
            for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count)) + 1):
                if count % i == 0:
                    prime = False
                    break
            if prime:
                self.append(count)
            count += 1
        return self # Note: self is Primes object which has a last method.

    def last(self, amount):
        ...
        return self

p = Primes()
p.first(5)
p.last(3)
# same as p = Primes().first(5).last(3) because it returns self
# Primes now inherits from list, so it works like a list but has a last method
```

I've fixed the tabbing in your code.

From the looks of it you don't need a last method at all. If you just want to get the last 5 values use [-5:].

```
# Your old way edited
class Primes():
    @staticmethod
    def first(amount):
       primes = []
       count = 1
       while len(primes) < amount:
            prime = True
            for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count)) + 1):
                if count % i == 0:
                    prime = False
                    break
            if prime:
                primes.append(count)
            count += 1
       return primes

p = Primes.first(20)
print(p)
print(p[-5:]) # This will give you the last 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time.

Comment: Your code had some incorrect tabbing. You don't need a last method. Just use the brackets to get the last 5 values.